# Installing maven using `apt-get install` overwrites Java8 with Java11

Tags: java, docker, maven, apt

Inside of my Dockerfile I am trying to simply add Maven to my image that already has a proper version of Java8. As in:

```
RUN apt-get install -y maven
```

When I do this, the install for `maven` brings along Java11 even thought I simply want to install Maven for the Java8 JDK I already have installed on the box. I am hoping there is some obvious solution to this that is clean and simple. I thought at first that the `apt-mark hold` might work, but I cannot figure out the name of the package to hold. For example, I tried

```
RUN  apt-mark hold default-jdk default-jre \
  && apt-get install -y maven
```

It seems very unfriendly of maven to install Java11 without any switch to tell it to either a) install Java8 or do not install Java and just trust that it is installed already.

Any ideas on how to install maven on ubuntu without this issue?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to install maven instead of using a maven wrapper?

Comment: Have you considered using a [Maven image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) instead of installing it?

Comment: @Turing85 I have not heard of a maven wrapper. I found a solution to my current problem, but if a wrapper is a more appropriate solution, can you give me a link ?

Comment: To make things clear. Maven does not install something...the issue is related to the dependencies given in the packages for ubuntu...... I would suggest to simply install it via: https://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems very unfriendly of maven to install Java11 without any switch to tell it to either a) install Java8 or do not install Java and just trust that it is installed already.

This is not really a Maven problem. When you do `apt-get insall`, the dependencies of the package are installed as well. But in case of Maven, you don't really need to install it with `apt-get`. You can simply download Maven with `wget` and unpack it.

Here is a `Dockerfile` example for this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:debian-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvzf apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz && \
    rm apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz

ENTRYPOINT [ "/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin/mvn", "--help" ]`
```

Or you could simply use a Maven image with Java 8:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-jdk-8

ENTRYPOINT [ "mvn", "--help" ]
``
```

Answer (score 2):

You now have two java versions on your systems. that is not a problem in itself.

Just select the version you want as default using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

See https://askubuntu.com/q/1288175 for details.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I found I could stop `Java11` from being installed by putting using the following 3 packages on hold:

```
RUN apt-mark hold default-jdk  \
  && apt-mark hold default-jre \
  && apt-mark hold default-jre-headless \
  && apt-get install -y maven
```

At least for my situation (`Corretto Java8 JDK` installed on a `Ubuntu 20` image) that marking these packages as on hold kept the `maven` install from updating the java version to 11.